# How can I implement an Angular directive similar to ngAttr?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I implement an Angular directive similar to ngAttr? This means a directive to match all the elements that start with a prefix.

Example: directive `myDirective` will match the attributes `data-my-directive-first`, `my-directive-second` and so on.

Comment: please write what have you tried.

Comment: I tried to look at the Angular source, but I couldn't find the source for the ngAttr directive. Using just `myDirective` when defining a directive will not match those attributes.

Comment: i think their is no way to find directive like that.

Comment: There is special hard logic for ngAttr* in collectDirectives function. collectDirectives is the function used for looking for directives on the given node and adding them to the directive collection which is sorted. So, what you want to achieve is not possible. You can patch angular if you wish :)

Comment: @AsishBhattarai, I guess you're referring to this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/92374f9633d6121b115d77c10248e40e1f4f2aa1/src/ng/compile.js#L1782, right? Could you please answer so I can accept and vote your answer?

Comment: @AdrianBer, yes, I was referring to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngAttr* is handled in angular in a special way. There is hard wired logic only meant for directives with ng-attr prefix. So, it is not possible what you want to achieve. You can see the logic in collectDirectives function which is used by angular to collect directives from HTML nodes. Here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/92374f9633d6121b115d77c10248e40e1f4f2aa1/src/ng/compile.js#L1759

My suggestion would be, have aliases' array and loop through to create directives with same function provided.